# Inline UIPickerView in a table

Tags: ios, uipickerview

In iOS 7, it's recommended to include pickers inline in a table.  Apple provided an example of an inline DatePicker (which you have posted a link to).  Is there a UIPickerView inline example?  I've tried to modify the UIDatePicker example & apply it to a UIPickerView, but it's not working. I looked on the Apple site and scoured the internet and have not found one.  I can post non-working code if necessary, but it's very long and thought I would ask the basic question first.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean "inline"? Why can't you just create it in a xib/storyboard, and have it appear inline to the other object?

Comment: What is the problem you are having? Post relevant code. The only difference between the two pickers is that with a `UIPickerView` you need to provide the data to the picker.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  If you look at the iOS Calendar app, you will see what I'm referring to.  If you add a new event to the calendar and click on the start and end dates, you will see that it presents the date pickers inline in the table.  It adds a row below the date you have selected to present the picker.

Comment: Hit return too soon.  Here's the code.  Warning, it's a little bit of a mess right now.

Comment: The code is too long.  Is there a place to upload a file?

Comment: This person is obviously new to SO, and I think he or she is being treated rather poorly. In iOS7, there is a facility to show/hide pickers in a UITableView. The DateCell sample shows this clearly for UIDatePickers. The OP is asking if there is a similar sample for UIPicker. The examples I have seen beg the same question. Anyway, I up voted the OP and maybe they will give SO another chance.