# How do I create an in-line picker for iOS for non-date/time values

Tags: ios, react-native, expo

Similar to [Inline UIPickerView in a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19843860/inline-uipickerview-in-a-table) but more focused on React Native and Expo and I am looking at it from the point of view of a tablet.

In React Native Community DateTimePicker it provides an in-line input of a time

[image]
[image]

However, they don't provide a similar function for non-time based pickers or at least I can't find it.  Is such a component not available in iOS because I can't seem to find something that behaves similarly where if you tap to show the picker and it starts editing the "original" disappears and places the field close to where it originally is.

I want it in-line as in a tablet the width is much larger so it does not make sense to do the [style as shown in the HIG](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/controls/pickers/) as it is for a phone form factor.

[react-native-dropdown-picker](https://hossein-zare.github.io/react-native-dropdown-picker-website/) is another one I tried to take a look at but it does not match what I would expect from the OS controls.